# how does a conditional operator return a subscript during assignment in Python?

Tags: python-3.x

i keep seeing the following in Python and i don't quite understand how it is working:

```
...
for label in range(1,5):
  indices = (y == label)  
  mu[label] = np.mean(x[indices,:], axis=0)
...
```

specifically `y==label` i expect to assign a boolean value to `indices` but then that var is used as a slice subscript?

appreciate any insight.

Comment: int(True)==1 and int(False)==0

Comment: `y` is evidently a numpy array, which defines all of the comparison operators to return a same-sized array of individual boolean results, rather than a single overall result.  The resulting array can be used as an index, to select all of the individual indexes where the comparison was true.

Comment: thanks @jasonharper. i missed that ```y==label``` indeed returns a matrix of boolean values the same size as ```y```